# After the iOS 7 update the weather app has changed my suburbs

Tags: ios

After updating my iPhone 5 to iOS 7 the weather app that comes on the phone has changed all my suburbs to Sydney.  I live in Mona Vale and also had Warriewood in there and Palm Beach but they all say Sydney.  Any ideas why?  I also cannot add them as they are not in the list of places even when I add by postcode they all come up as Sydney.

Answer (score 1):

The effect is in Mac OS X's Dashboard weather widget, and iOS 5 weather app as well. All Australian suburb data appears to have been removed, and redirected to the encompassing city.

Since both are sourcing from Yahoo, it would be safe to assume either Apple is no longer getting the data, or Yahoo has stopped providing it - I'd speculate that perhaps the bureau of meteorology has changed their terms for access to the data.

Kindof makes the iOS "Local weather" option useless.